# show progress with a lengthy background job that does not come back for a long time

Tags: multithreading, background, progress-bar, worker

Winform.
I have a long job  that is handled by a background worker.
While the bg worker is running, I show a status bar with the message "please wait" with a an animated gif.
However, I would like to show a progress count of some kind, even if this is an estimated number.
For example, 10%, 20%, etc.
The problem is that the bg job executes a stored procedure that does not come back until it is finished (100 minutes), so it is not as if I have a loop that I can call worker.ReportProgress(percentageComplete).

Do I need a second bg worker that I can set up to do a loop and call worker.ReportProgress(percentageComplete)? if yes, how do bg worker 1 (the one that executes the storedprocedure that does not come back until a long time) tells bg worker 2 to finish so it stops (in case bg worker 1 completes before the estimated time?)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue with a good enough solution for now: added a 2nd bg worker to paint the progress in the status bar (shows % progress every so often with an estimated time). Once worker1 completes, it shows the message in the UI.
The only thing, worker2 must finish before worker1, otherwise "job completed" will show before it actually finished.
For now this is good enough, I will use this only when the job is very long (this is known), otherwise, the animated gif + "please wait" will suffice.